# Absolute div overlapping sibling on resize, css solution or only with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to fix with css only (if possible) an overlapping absolute positioned div at the bottom of a fixed div in a sidebar.
Although it would be possible to detect this and modify the position of the absolute div with javascript, I was wondering if there is an easier css only solution.
I tried to add the padding of the height of the bottom element to the fixed parent, but it keeps overlapping it on resize (vertical)-
So how to prevent the bottom element to overlap the unordered list in case (1) the window is too small or (2) the list is too long.

html:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        <li>list item</li>
        ...     
    </ul>
    <div id="bottom_element">
        <p>I am a bottom element</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#bottom_element {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
}

#sidebar > ul {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

An example of the code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ax9ssstj/).
Updated code with jquery: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ax9ssstj/1/)
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: where do you expect it to be?  I look at the html/css and it looks like it's behaving what the css tells it to.  So what is the expected outcome?

Comment: Can you explain how the current behaviour differs from what you'd like to happen?

Comment: Sorry if was not clear, I am trying to stop the overlapping and have a scroll on the fixed div if there is an overflow-y, as if the absolute element would become relative (which I think could be a javascript approach). Thanks.

Comment: Still unclear, which element overlaps which element?

Comment: @LGSon
On resizing the browser or watching on a smaller screen the bottom element overlaps the ul.

Comment: As your bottom element has position absolute it is taken out of the flow, which makes the other elements slide beneath when there is no space left. Setting a min height on sidebar will somewhat prevent this. Why do you have the bottom element set to position absolute?

Comment: @LGSon, because I would like to have the bottom element always visible at the bottom whenever possible (so until the ul gets overlapped). I guess the easiest way would be to than grab the ul height with js and apply that to the min height of the sidebar. I see how this could work. Thanks for this insight on min-height.

Comment: @LGSon, so I was wondering if something similar to this is possible with css alone, not changing the position of course, but just making the scroll possible. See updated fiddle in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is way that might help you move on, where the "bottom" element always stays at the bottom when the ul list has to few items, and when many item, then bottom element gets pushed down instead of overlap the list.

```css
*, *:before, *.after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background: #ddd;
    overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.page-row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 0;
}
.page-row-expanded {
    height: 100%;
}

.bottom div {
    background-color: #bbb;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="page-row page-row-expanded">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>
          <li>list item</li>   
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom page-row">
      <div>
        Bottom element
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @LGSon, unfortunately this is more or less what I had in the beginning; an overlapping ul by the bottom element. What I really tried to achieve is as it looks in the updated fiddle in my question, but without javascript, as I was hoping for a css only solution.

Comment: You want the bottom element to be pushed down instéad of staying and have the sidebar to scroll?

Comment: Correct, only leaving the bottom fixed at bottom inside the sidebar when it is not overlapping the ul.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and, having read this (and other posts), I used this solution...

```
// divid is the ID of the element with position: absolute
function SetHeight(divid) {
  var divh = $("#"+divid).height();
// 36 is the maximum height before overlay occurs 
  if (divh > 36) {
    $("#"+divid).css("position", "relative");
  }
}
```

I hope it is of some use to others.
This my first post so if I've got things wrong please excuse me.